# Запятая перед "и" в предложении из Контракта

Tags: пунктуация

работаю над составлением Контрактов. Возникают вопросы по орфографии и пунктуации, так как неправильно расставленные знаки препинания могут изменить смысл предложения. А это деньги. Подскажите, в этом предложении из Контракта нужна запятая перед "и", или нет?

"Работы должны быть выполнены в объеме, указанном в пункте договора, и в срок до 23 августа".

Comment: Не извольте сомневаться. Если вы оборот открыли запятой  перед "указанном", то его ведь и закрыть надо?!

Answer (score 1):

*Работы должны быть выполнены в объеме, **указанном в пункте договора**, и в срок до 23 августа.*

Пунктуация верная (обособление причастного оборота), но вот зачем нужны лишние слова, относительно которых приходится сомневаться.

Что изменится, если написать так: *Работы должны быть выполнены в объеме, **указанном в пункте договора**, до 23 августа.*

Или: *Работы должны быть выполнены  в объеме,  **указанном в договоре**, до 23 августа.*